# Finding Frequency of each letter in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame which looks the following:

```
col1 col2 col3
A     B    A
C     A    D
E     A    B
```

I need to find total number of occurrences of the letters A,B,C,D and E.

I have used lapply along with table function in the following manner:

```
z =apply(T[,1:3],2,table)
```

It gives a list of frequency of each letter in each column. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try `table(unlist(df))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
table(as.matrix(dat))
```

or as RStudent suggested:

```
table(unlist(dat))
```

**data**

```
dat<- read.table(text="col1;col2;col3
A;B;A
C;A;D
E;A;B
", header=TRUE, sep=";")
```